# Storing list into CSV file from webscraping via selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, selenium

Warning: new to python and programming

Objective: Scrape all job links from this page and place into a txt/csv/json/XML file: https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=title%3Aengineer&l=Vancouver%2C+BC

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=engineer&l=Vancouver%2C+BC&sort=date')
jobs = browser.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Engineer')
for job in jobs:
    print(job.get_attribute("href"))
with open("output.csv",'w') as resultFile:
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile)
    wr.writerow(jobs)
```

It works great when it prints the results, but it doesn't store anything in the csv file. Also, I plan to make this scrape more than 1 page, so what would be the best way in modifying the csv file in a way that expands the links, not overwrites them?

Comment: have you tried  using `bs4.BeautifulSoup(link)`

Comment: havent tried bs4, very new to this. i will give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not writen to csv because the input `jobs` in `wr.writerow(jobs)` is not valid, you can do

```
with open("output.csv",'w') as resultFile:
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile)
    wr.writerow([j.get_attribute("href") for j in jobs])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is strange looking `for jobs in jobs:`. Are you sure you didn't mean to write `for job in jobs:`? And that is probably your problem.  You are stomping on your `jobs` iterable.

Take a look at this example:

```
>>> numbers = [1,2,3,4]
>>> numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> type(numbers)
<type 'list'>
>>> for numbers in numbers:
...     print numbers
...
1
2
3
4
>>> numbers
4
>>> type(numbers)
<type 'int'>
```

It isn't the `print numbers` that is turning `numbers` into an `int`.  Observe:

```
>>> numbers = [1,2,3,4]
>>> type(numbers)
<class 'list'>
>>> for numbers in numbers:
...    print(":)")
...    
:)
:)
:)
:)
>>> type(numbers)
<class 'int'>
>>> numbers
4
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the terminal is still running.
That trick was to get the href attribute from the browser_find_elements_by_partial_link. It seems to print the links just fine, problem comes with storing them.

Comment: so what's happening here, the list turned to int after print...
thanks for the lead, i will try to make it work and re-read your first comment

Comment: It is not the `print` that cause `numbers` to become an `int` it the for loop.